# Trying to make a div appear when hovering over an image

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a div with some information about an image appear when I hover over the image, my code doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
< div class="batmobile-info">This is Batman's batmobile, he uses it to chase his enemies or to flee from the police.< /div>
 < img class="batmobile" src="images/batmobile.png" alt="batmobile" >
```

CSS:

```
.batmobile{
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:200px;
top:350px;
left:200px;
}

.batmobile-info{
visibility:hidden;
}

.batmobile:hover .batmobile-info{
background-color:white;
text-align:center;
width:290px;
height:40px;
position:absolute;
top:500px;
left:700px;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Where should this "information div" appear? Should it overlay the image? Should it appear somewere else?

Comment: It should appear above the image.

Comment: I've already set its position with ´top:500px;
left:700px;´

Comment: `.batmobile:hover .batmobile-info` looks for an element with the class `batmobile-info` that 's a descendant of an element with the class `batmobile`. That's not your hierarchy and there is no previous element selector is CSS. You'll either need JavaScript or to rearrange your elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the order of your elements, so the `img` comes before the `div` to give you:

```
<img class="batmobile" src="images/batmobile.png" alt="batmobile">
<div class="batmobile-info">This is Batman's batmobile, he uses it to chase his enemies or to flee from the police.</div>
```

Then you could use the following CSS to show the `div` on hover:

```
.batmobile:hover + .batmobile-info {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

The `+` is an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) - a super useful selector!

Comment: Did this and it worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work is to use container where you'll put your `img` and `div` with information.

I used `opacity` instead of `visibility` because `opactity` is the property you can use in transitions.

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
/* contiainer to center my content, not relevant to question*/
.main-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 2rem);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
/* image and info container */
.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
/* style for div with information */
.img-info {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #eee;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: .5rem;
}
/* information positioning styles */
.img-info-overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img-info-above {
  left: -2px;
  top: -2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
}
/* this part show information on hover */
.img-container:hover .img-info {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x100/fff/aaa" alt="Filler image">
    <div class="img-info img-info-overlay">Some info about this image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x100/fff/aaa" alt="Filler image">
    <div class="img-info img-info-above">Some info about this image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in both - the HTML and CSS, you need to put the image and text in one parent block and start styling from it. I'd avoid absolute positioning and also try using [opacity CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) in case you will need to add some extra transition effects to your text block `.batmobile:hover` state. Check out the code and run the snippet:

```css
body {background:#ccc}

.batmobile {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px
}

.batmobile div p {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto; /* Think you wanted to center the block as width is less than parent */
  text-align: center /*In case you need to center text only */
}

.batmobile:hover div p {
  visibility: visible;
}

.batmobile img {width: 100%}
```

```html
<div class="batmobile">
 
  <div>
  <p>An excelent drone - Ryze Tello with price under $100</p>
  </div>

  <img src="https://bestdroneforkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/ryze-tello-drone-forkids.jpg" alt="Ryze tello drone in the air">

</div>
```